# installing APKs outside of android market

Tags: android, deployment

I want to install an app/idea i have developed int a demo on my phone (HTC Hero). I have read several posts some from as far back as '08 on different options. I was hoping I could install this using the debug bridge and eclipse, but can't seem to find a way.

Is there an easy way for me to get this on my phone?

Thanks in advance,
Pat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yea it's easy, provided you don't have AT&T. If you don't, just go to Settings->Applications->Development and check USB debugging.

From there, you plug your phone into your computer using the USB cord, and when you launch your app like you normally would with the virtual console, it ought to detect your device. Specify that you want to launch on your device, and it will install it no problem.

If you are on an AT&T phone, you will have to root it to allow non-market apks to be installed.

Comment: Did not know that about AT&T phones.  That's pretty depressing.

Comment: Yea AT&T isn't very user friendly... I would provide a link to rooting but its really based on preference and the model you have, there are so many different options it's not really worth listing them all.

Comment: Update: HTC Phones will work as long as you provide a permissions file in usb.d in Linux. Otherwise the phone shows as "??????????" in DDMS and ADV in Eclipse

Answer (score 0):

Other way of installing application on your device is that you can upload your apk file on the web server and download it by opening the link in your web browser. But insure that you must have enabled the option `Unknown Sources` in your `Settings>>Application` on your device.